# Sending requests on invalid route on nextjs app is returning 404 not found but in application insights, some internal localhost request returns 200OK

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-webapps, appinsights

We have come across an unusual problem where sending a request to an invalid route results in a 404 not found status code, which is the expected behavior. However, when we checked the application insight logs, it showed a 200 OK response on internal calls.

I have attached a screenshot for reference, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening.

[image: end to end transaction details]